# Is there an equivalent in C# to this Java code?

Tags: c#, java, multithreading

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                //Code to execute on thread.start();
            }};

        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

In C# Code i want to start a new thread. But i want to keep the code which will be executed in the new thread in the same method in which the thread is started because i think it is more readable code. Like in the Java example above.

How will the equivalent code in C# look like?

Comment: That code does not create a Thread. You just execute the run() method of the Runnable in your current thread. If you want a thread, you need to do `new Thread(yourRunnable).start()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [a `Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) to achieve this:

```
public class ThreadTest {

  public static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
    Task task = new Task(() => ... // Code to run here);
    task.Start();
  }
}
```

As @JonSkeet points out, if you do not need to separate creation and scheduling you could use:

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ... // Code to run here);
```

Or in .Net 4.5+:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() =>  ... // Code to run here);
```

Comment: +1 Because Task approach is the recommended async programming approach since .NET 4

Comment: I'd probably suggest using Task.Factory.StartNew or Task.Run from .NET 4.5 though.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) or a [Anonymous Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => /* Code to execute */);
t.Start();
```